# Missing CA certificates in truststore.jks on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters

I have implemented a security adapter which talks to **Twitter for OAuth**. In local MFP developer server, the request to Twitter works (after I have added the respective CA certificates to the local keys.jks file).
When running on Bluemix, it has some CA certificates installed in trustore.jks, but unfortunately, not complete (see below)

*QUESTION: How can I add certificates to the truststore.jks? It's in the local fileystem of Bluemix. (Added in the certs to the keytore configured under Runtime Settings does not do the trick as this keystore is not used for outbound SSL).*

Error in Log:

```
App/0
[ERROR ] CWPKI0022E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE: A signer with SubjectDN CN=api.twitter.com, OU=Twitter Security, O="Twitter, Inc.", L=San Francisco, ST=California, C=US was sent from the target host. The signer might need to be added to local trust store /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/mfp/resources/security/truststore.jks, located in SSL configuration alias defaultSSLConfig. The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
2016-09-21T20:33:00.614+0200
App/0
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:
2016-09-21T20:33:00.614+0200
App/0
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
2016-09-21T20:33:00.618+0200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the truststore.jks file from the filesystem, add the certificates you need to add, and then upload it back to server by going to the "Advanced Settings" section of the Mobile Foundation service tile in the Bluemix console and uploading it there.  Note that this action recreates the server, so if you are using the free Developer plan, you'll lose whatever you have in the in-memory Derby database and will effectively have to "start over".  If you're using a paid plan that uses DashDB, the contents of the DB will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate can be added via the MobileFirst Server Operations Console. Use the Runtime Settings -> Keystore -> Configure Keystore option to upload the custom keystore.

1) You can create your keystore using the keytool utility.

2) Add the missing certificate to the keystore using the keytool -importcert option.

3) Upload the keystore using the Operations Console